# Change order of operation applied to a dask bag

Tags: dask

I am using a dask bag to handle parallelization of data processing on traces collected from a set of experiments. The paths to the data files for each experiment are turned into custom objects and common operations I perform on this type of data are object methods.

Each object has an identification number associated with the particular experiment. And at some point in the program I want to use this ID number to remove some of the experiments. As in this task graph, where a object is created from a sequence, detrending and deconvolution functions are then applied followed by a remove operation.

[image: dask task graph]
Because experiment identification number is static the remove operation can be performed at any step in the task graph and the end result will be the same. However if the remove operation is performed following other computationally costly methods the result will be mush slower, due to these computations being performed unnecessarily on objects that will end up being removed.

Is there a way to insert an operation at an earlier point in the task graph for the bag so that if someone adds a remove operation at any point, it will be the first operation performed?

Comment: maybe: A. store the id as something within the bag, selectively add task according to the id. or B. only compute tasks you want, instead of every tasks you added to the dask graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using dask bag you might want to look at dask delayed, which might give you a bit more flexibility:

http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html

If you really want to muck about with the task graph directly then you should read about the graph specification

http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/spec.html

Comment: Thank you. I have a solution working with dask delayed.